# Active dots class on Slick Slider with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

so I'm using slick slider on my ReactJS app, by the config I set custom class from my modular CSS, slick slider dots active class (".slick-active) is automatically toggled
but my CSS wont applied, how is the proper way to style the active state of the dots
thanks in advance,

```
import style  from "./MainSlider.module.scss";

const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    speed: 1500,
    autoplay: true,
    dotsClass: style.slickDots,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
};


<Slider {...settings}>
        {
            sliderItems.map((sliderItem, idx) => (
                <div key={idx} className={style.sliderItem}>
                    <div className={style.image}>
                        <img src={sliderItem.image} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.text}>
                        <p>{sliderItem.title}</p>
                        <Link to="/service" className={style.more}>
                            <img src={ViewMore} alt=""/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </Slider>
```

this is my MainSlider.module.scss

```
.slider {
width: 70vw;
height: 70vh;
.slickDots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    li{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        &.slick-active {
            background: magenta !important;
            button {
                &::before {
                    background: red;
                }
            }
        }
        button {
            font-size: 0;
            line-height: 0;
            display: block;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border:2px solid white;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            background: transparent;
            &::before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                content: ' ';
                color: black;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

- I add image instead of code so it will be more readable and can help you understand more about my problem
  [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppYwe.png)

Comment: Please show codesandbox instead a image

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question with code

Answer (score 0):

For applying your styles to global styles, like slick-active in `css-modules` you should use this approach:

```css
:global(.slick-active) {
  background-color: red;
}
```